# "Recursive types for free!" -- But doesn't this contradict the fact that $\mathbb{N} \notin \mathbf{FinSet}$?

Tags: category-theory, lambda-calculus, type-theory

From what I understand based on [Philip Wadler's](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/free-rectypes/free-rectypes.txt) comment, polymorphic lambda calculus has least fixed points for all its covariant endofunctors. Here's a quote:

> Thus, it is safe to extend the polymorphic lambda calculus by adding least fixpoint types with type variables in positive position. Indeed, no extension is required: such types already exist in the language! If $F X$ represents a type containing $X$ in positive position only, then least fixpoints may be defined in terms of universal quantification:
>
> $$\mathrm{Lfix}_X F X  =  \forall X[(F X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X]$$

On so many levels, I don't get this, but to keep this question brief I'll just emphasize one thing that's bugging me about it. A special case of Philip Wadler's comment is that $$\mathbb{N} \cong \forall X[(1+X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X].$$ But if this is true, then it means that $\mathbf{FinSet}$ can't interpret the polymorphic lambda calculus with sum types. But surely it can, because polymorphic lambda calculus is just like the simply typed calculus, but with type variables and a mechanism for doing generics? What am I missing here?

Comment: What is defined a categorical interpretation of PLC? (A quick google search suggests that it is not straightforward to define such a notion.) More specifically, how do you interpret the universal quantification over type variables? Because this seems to be the catch there, already with something as simple as the polymorphic identity which is of type $\forall\alpha.\alpha\to\alpha$.

Comment: @Pece, I dunno. Maybe $\forall \alpha.\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ could be interpreted the type of natural transformations from the identity functor to itself? I guess that was my assumption.

Comment: "On so many levels, I don't get this": not your question, but that comment is talking about Church-encoding (or more precisely its typed version, the Böhm-Berarducci encoding).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what is the source of confusion here exactly, so let me note some things:

First, the following two statements are not contradictory

1. A type theory has an infinite type, i.e. a type with infinite number of judgementally distinct closed terms.
2. A type theory has a model where closed types are finite sets.

Example: simply typed lambda calculus with an empty base type `ι`. It has the type `(ι → ι) → (ι → ι)` with countably infinite closed terms, and also a model where `ι` is the empty set, hence all types are finite sets.

In the other direction, we can also interpret `ι` as the set of natural numbers. So, having finite set models doesn't say much about finiteness of syntactic types.

Also, note that the relation between polymorphic LC (or: System F) and simply typed LC is rather tenuous. The former is not merely the latter with some features thrown in. The expressive power of System F is vastly beyond STLC. The proof-theoretic strength of System F is the same as that of second-order arithmetic, with no known combinatorial description.

Comment: System F does have _a_ (finite) set model: the booleans. It's just fairly trivial, similar to the example given for the simple type case.

Comment: @DanDoel How does that work, do you have a reference? BTW, by finite set model I meant that every closed type must be a finite set; if we allow closed types to be other than sets, then we have e.g. the trivial (terminal) model where every type is the element of the singleton set.

Comment: Every inhabited type denotes the singleton set (and thus every term is an irrelevant witness to its type's truth); every uninhabited type denotes the empty set. The universal quantifier only quantifies over two things, so it is equivalent to the binary product of the two possible instantiations. [Here](https://hub.darcs.net/dolio/agda-share/browse/F.agda) is an Agda formalization. It's at least a little interesting, because you can imagine it to be an impredicative propositional calculus where Church encodings allow you to define most of the connectives (since you're only given Π and →).

Comment: Oh, another thing to note is that the Reynolds proof uses the fact that you can instantiate a Π to a set with more than one element. So this shows (I think) that the only (classical) set theoretic models that can exist are 'trivial' in that they assign all types to sets with at most one element. It's also the case that you can have constructive set theories that are able to interpret System F in a straight forward way, as in "Polymorphic is Set Theoretic Constructively." I'm not terribly familiar with the details of that, though.

Comment: The reason _that_ can work is that Reynolds' proof essentially shows that there is a fixed point of $(- → 2) → 2$, which is classically false. However, there are anti-classical axioms that allow you to show the natural numbers are a fixed point. See [here](http://math.andrej.com/2009/10/12/constructive-gem-double-exponentials/) for instance. I don't know about the status of constructive, non-trivial _finite_ set models, though.

Comment: @DanDoel That is surprising to me, because System F type inhabitation is undecidable, and from your code it would follow that it's decidable. On the first look, your Agda code misses a coercion rule for terms, so it's not exactly the syntax of System F, and perhaps that's the problematic case. I'll check what happens there. It's also weird to me that predicative MLTT can prove impredicative F consistent.

Comment: @DanDoel: your code works with full System F syntax, so we do get consistency: https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/master/agda/SystemFBooleanModel/BooleanModel.agda. I'd like to see if we can massage this so that we get an inhabitant as well, that would be *really* surprising.

Comment: @DanDoel: after looking at this more, it seems that the Boolean model is sound but not provably complete, so we don't get decidable inhabitation, as expected. The consistency result is still very interesting, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Oh, I see the discrepancy. My description of the model is inaccurate, and System F is not complete for the model. For instance $∀ a. ¬¬a → a$ denotes true, but there is no System F term with that type. Thus, you cannot use this to get a term. I think the explanation for why Agda can do this is we are treating F as an overcomplicated propositional logic, and it's not surprising that Agda can show that consistent (though note we had to use a classical model).

Comment: Honestly Andras, rereading your answer many times, I'm not sure I understand it. From what I gather from Phillip's comment, $\forall X[(1+X \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X]$ represents, not just a type with infinitely many closed terms, but specifically, the least fixed point of the function $X \mapsto 1 + X$. But this functor has no least fixed point in $\mathbf{FinSet}$. So, it seems to me that $\mathbf{FinSet}$ is not a model of System F. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, I think I get it now. It's true that $\mathbf{FinSet}$ is not a model of System F, because $\forall X.FX$ would be interpreted as $\lim_{X : \mathbf{FinSet}} FX$, whereas I had in mind something more like $\prod_{x : X} F(x)$. The latter can be interpreted in $\mathbf{FinSet}$ just fine, but doesn't fit with the meaning of $\forall X$, which is where my confusion was probably coming from. Can you confirm that I've understood correctly?

Comment: Also, it seems to me that System F is very weird and non-classical in nature. In particular, if we can take finite coproducts, then we can build the type $2 := 1 + 1$, which allows us to build the type $\forall X.2$, which is an object of the universe that's actually, from the point of view of classical mathematics, bigger than the universe. If so, then it seems to me that System F contains "anti-classical" axioms that are outright inconsistent with the classical way of doing mathematics. Is this correct?

Comment: @goblin: Dan Doel has given above a model in the category $\mathbf 1$, where $1+1 \cong 1$. That's also a (degenerate) model in the larger category FinSet, even tho 
in the singleton set model, sums don't work as you expect, and $1+1 \cong 1$ only holds in the smaller category.

Comment: @goblin And as you say, F does not have (nontrivial) classical set-theoretic models; comments above refer to Reynolds' proof: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076261/document. "Polymorphic is Set Theoretic Constructively" is a followup that gives an anticlassical set-theoretic model.